# Moving Django 1.3 to new server

Tags: django

I'm trying to move website made in Django 1.3.

Server is set up as the privies one (I think so).

After Django installation, I moved all files to new server, I swap settings files so now in settings are files from the privies server. I changed files locations in setting, so right now all are pointed to sew server location.
Also some modules was missing which I install and I don’t get errors with missing django modules.

When I'm trying to set visible on internet, I get following errors:

```
[root@575283 somod]# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>
  execute_manager(settings)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
  utility.execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 209, in execute
  translation.activate('en-us')
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 100, in activate
  return _trans.activate(language)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 202, in activate
  _active.value = translation(language)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 185, in translation
  default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 162, in _fetch
  app = import_module(appname)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
  __import__(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sorl_thumbnail-11.12-py2.6.egg/sorl/thumbnail/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  from sorl.thumbnail.fields import ImageField
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sorl_thumbnail-11.12-py2.6.egg/sorl/thumbnail/fields.py", line 2, in <module>
  from django.db import models
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
  connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
  backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 33, in load_backend
  return import_module('.base', backend_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
  __import__(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 14, in <module>
  raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

I'm guessing I missed MySQLdb module, any tips?

Also what bout other output lines?

Old server has Django 1.3
I'm using CentOS 6, Apache 2, Django 1.3.1, mod_wsgi, Python 2.6.6

Comment: So, have you installed MySQLdb or not?  And the rest of output is called traceback.

Comment: Why are you doing `runserver` if you're using mod_wsgi?

Comment: Because I'm noob. I have problem with MySQLdb installation. What should i do? I read guids for last few days, and i dont know what to do right now. I started one week ago and i still dont see any results :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install [MySQL-python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python). You can install it using [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html):

`sudo pip install MySQL-python`

If you need help on how to run Django with Apache, see [the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/). If they are confusing, [keep Googling](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=sv&sclient=psy-ab&q=how%20to%20server%20django%20with%20apache%20wsgi&oq=how%20to%20server%20django%20with%20apache%20wsgi&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...2231.2809.0.2872.5.5.0.0.0.0.84.258.5.5.0...0.0.G58deIDVKsk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=393b2ac78977d9cd&biw=2504&bih=1346&ion=1).

Good luck :)

Comment: `[root@575283 ~]# sudo pip install MySQLdb
Downloading/unpacking MySQLdb
  Real name of requirement MySQLdb is MySQLdb
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement MySQLdb
No distributions at all found for MySQLdb
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
`

Comment: MySQLdb requires some specific dependencies and often doesn't compile straight out of the box. You should run `sudo apt-get build-dep python-mysqldb` first. That will install all the dependencies and then you can use `pip` to install MySQLdb.

Comment: Thanks, i already did that and i have MySQL-python. Right now i have problem with `DocumentRoot /var/www/vhost/domain/httpdocs` - its in httpd.conf . I'm getting error for `[root@575283 conf]# /etc/init.d/httpd restart`: `Starting httpd: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/vhost/domain/httpdocs] does not exist`. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, does the directory exist? If not create it. Other than that, you need to open a new question.